# How is startId handled by Services in Android?

Tags: android, android-service

So we can start a service by calling `startService` and providing it an intent. Internally Android somehow calls `onStartCommand` with a `startId`.

Now, it is suggested that we should call `stopSelf(startId)` within a `Service` so that our `Service` doesn't stop just after a new request for starting it has been received. My doubt is that how does `stopSelf(startId)` internally keeps track of when to stop and when not. I tried diving into [cs.android.com](https://cs.android.com) but I am unable to see the exact code where `stopSelf` is making the decision of when to stop the service.